# Applescript auto select email

Tags: email, applescript

I'm trying to write a script selects the first email if less than an hour and grabs the email, and then auto selects the next email if less than an hour and grabs the email till the email is greater than the hour.

I can grab the first email, but getting the second one is what I can't think on how to do.

Direction is what I'm looking for, instead of just the answer, I just need to where to start.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theMessage to message 1 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Google"
    set theDate to date received of theMessage

    if theDate is less than the (current date) and (theDate) is greater than ((current date) - (1 * hours)) then
        set theEmail to the (address of to recipient of theMessage)

    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your code inside of a repeat loop:

```
repeat with oneMessage in every message of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Google"
     set theDate to date received of theMessage
     --Conditional analysis
end repeat
```

The main problem with this code is the possibility of have a HUGE number of messages in your INBOX, thereby bogging down the script.

Another alternative is to just grab all the messages less than an hour old in a single command,  and then deal with the resulting list:

```
set oneHourMessages to every message of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Google" whose date received is less than the (current date) and date received is greater than ((current date) - (1 * hours))
```

Good luck,